# Is it possible to get a value from view.yml in an action

Tags: view, symfony1, action, configuration-files

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the name of a stylesheet from view.yml in an action, ideally using something as simple as:

```
sfConfig::get('......');
```

I'd like to access the existing declaration in view.yml instead of hardcoding it or duplicating it somewhere like app.yml.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to get name of a stylesheet in controller? According to the MVC idea controller has nothing to do with appearance. So it seems weird.

Comment: It's too complex to explain in a few words, don't worry about it, I have a good reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access the current Module's Config, you can use:

```
sfViewConfigHandler::getConfiguration(array(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/view.yml'));
```

It should return something like this:

```
Array
(
[indexSuccess] => Array
    (
        [javascripts] => Array
            (
                [0] => mission-control.js
            )

        [stylesheets] => Array
            (
                [0] => control-box.css
                [1] => question.css
            )

    )

[newSuccess] => Array
    (
        [javascripts] => Array
            (
                [0] => box-checker.js
                [1] => topic.js
            )

        [stylesheets] => Array
            (
                [0] => question.css
                [1] => topic.css
            )

    )

[searchSuccess] => Array
    (
        [javascripts] => Array
            (
                [0] => topic.js
            )

        [stylesheets] => Array
            (
                [0] => topic.css
            )

    )

[showSuccess] => Array
    (
        [javascripts] => Array
            (
                [0] => mission-control.js
            )

        [stylesheets] => Array
            (
                [0] => control-box.css
                [1] => question.css
            )

    )

[editSuccess] => Array
    (
        [javascripts] => Array
            (
                [0] => box-checker.js
                [1] => topic.js
            )

        [stylesheets] => Array
            (
                [0] => question.css
                [1] => topic.css
            )

    )

[all] => Array
    (
        [stylesheets] => Array
            (
            )

        [javascripts] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. I found something similar earlier and I guess returning all of it is the only way.

Comment: And this is what works out-of-the-box: $config_array = sfViewConfigHandler::getConfiguration(array(sfConfig::get('sf_app_config_dir').'/view.yml'));