# How to get the name of the current layout?

Tags: layout, symfony1

symfony [getLayout](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction#method_getlayout) does not seem to work when layout is set via view.yml. Is there anyway to get this within the controller's action class method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a trivial task. The view.yml, is not in the "scope" of the action.
Maybe, you can use setLayout in your action rather then in view.yml.
if you can't, for some reasons... you can try this method to reach datas in view.yml:
[Is it possible to get a value from view.yml in an action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192769/is-it-possible-to-get-a-value-from-view-yml-in-an-action)

Comment: Hi dxb, thank you for the very response. I would prefer to use view.yml as it seems a much cleaner way to set layout, but seems like I have no choice but to set it in action unless I want to read the view.yml (which seems to be adding overhead).

Comment: My situation is: I started to use pjax on my site, however since with pjax I replace a certain div that is within a parent div (which has different class depending on the layout), I wanted to use the layout name to set the class of the parent div in pjax requests. After checking all the options, I decided that I actually should have NOT used different layouts in the first place, so I ended up going back and changed (lots of) my code to remove layout. But all your pointers are very useful for me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed this. You can do it but you just need to return the entire view.yml contents as an array:

```
$view_array = sfViewConfigHandler::getConfiguration(array(sfConfig::get('sf_app_config_dir').'/‌​view.yml'));
```

Just adjust the relative path from sf_app_config_dir (or use another marker) to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following code in the action. It works for both cases, layout set in the action or in the view.yml.

```
$controller = $this->getContext()->getController();
$view = $controller->getView($this->getModuleName(), $this->getActionName(), 'Success');  // viewName == 'Success' (default)
$layout_name = $view->getDecoratorTemplate();  // e.g expected: layout.php
```

Let us know if it works for you.